# How to forward data via netns exec namespace

Tags: ubuntu, python, port-forwarding, namespace, mqtt

I'm using zmq to receive data from another pc. I would like to formard this received data to the Internet via namespace. I've created this python script:

```
import subprocess
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://10.1.24.50:4000")
socket.subscribe("")
while True:
    print("message rcv")
    data = socket.recv_string() 
    command = ['sudo', 'ip', 'netns', 'exec', 'ue1', 'ping', '-i', '1', '-c', '1', '-s', str(len(data)), '8.8.8.8'] 
    print(data)
    subprocess.run(command, input=data, text=True)
```

When I execute the script in a terminal I get this output.

```
message rcv
Lat 41.283637867194834, Lon=1.9846894680137672
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 46(74) bytes of data.
54 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=184 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 184.334/184.334/184.334/0.000 ms
```

However, I don't see the transmitted data (using wireshark).

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is 8.8.8.8 there just as a plug to stand in for real data? If not, you are trying to send the data to a Google.com DNS server. I doubt that's what you intend. Please clarify what in your code is real and what is there to mask data for security purposes.

Comment: Right, my goal is to send the data to a private edge/cloud service, however, I'm using 8.8.8.8 to check if the data is detected. I can change this IP for the one shown with a different port "4001".